# blank page when deploying to heroku MERN

Tags: heroku, deployment, mern

I'm struggling with deploying a web app to Heroku. Everything seems fine, there are not errors shown, but I only get a blank page.

I've been searching around the internet and tried everything I saw but can't seem to find the answer.

server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build/index.html'))
);
```

folders:

[image]

I don't know what else to attach, just tell me and I'll provide it. Thank you very very much in advance, this is really really important to me

Comment: Is the blank page you mentioned an `Application-Error (Error Heroku Logs) Page` in  Heroku?

Comment: Hi there. Nope, it's just a blank page :(

Comment: Is any of your other routes working?

Comment: no, everything blank. (just to say: locally it works perfectly)

Comment: If this is a public repo? Can you share the link?

Comment: It's not on github yet, I was deploying through git not github. I can upload it tomorrow,  but I'm not really allowed to make it public :( I could try and ask, but on the meantime, is there any other file you consider it could be helpful for you to see? I can edit the post right now

Comment: hey @JaganKaartik. sorry to bother, still having trouble with this :( do u think the code I attached from server.js is correct?

Comment: Hey @pop I have added an answer below. I think you should change `('*')` to `('/*')` in your server.js.

Answer (score 2):

Generally,

If you want to deploy your entire MERN app to Heroku, first you add a `heroku-postbuild` script to `package.json`

In your case, since you have directories `frontend`, `backend` containing the client and server respectively.

Add these scripts to your `package.json`, these scripts will `build` your react frontend after the push to heroku.

```js
...
"scripts": {
    "install-client":"cd frontend && npm install"
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build"
}
...
```

Now in your `server.js` file,

```js
...

const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build', 'index.html'));
});

...
```

Now, if you need to use Client-Side Routing (React Router) update `/` to `/*` as shown below,

```js
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

I think this should resolve the issue.

Refer: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Hey!! Just seen this. Thank you very much for your help. I manage to fix the problem but I'm still not sure how tbh haha. I think the problem was that I had a /manifest.json instead of manifest.json in the index.html.. But, anyways, thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to deploy both the backend and frontend together from heroku?

In the past I've used heroku for my backend and used netlify for deploying my frontend

Comment: hey! yep, I'm trying to deploy both from heroku. But you deployed from different services in the same project?

Comment: yeah I looked at several tutorials but I think this is a good one  [medium article](https://dev.to/stlnick/how-to-deploy-a-full-stack-mern-app-with-heroku-netlify-ncb)